# Unable to call Tkinter module in Python2.7 for some reason

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am unable to call Tkinter from text editor(sublime) OR interpreter..

I did a fresh Debian install on Virtualbox with ActivePython2.7

Here is a video on 1.5min for easier explanation on my problem!

Thanks for your time, guys!

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIj3KuzaNpM**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python2.x it is:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

For python3.x it is:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Now as you are using `python 2.7` you should be using `from Tkinter import *`

However it would be better to use:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0]==2:
    from Tkinter import *
if sys.version_info[0]==3:
    from tkinter import *
```

in order to avoid any future problem

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can help you:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-b98d59735c04>", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
ImportError: No module named tkinter

>>> import Tkinter
>>>
```